# Интеграция таблицы в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Как я понимаю, для того чтобы создать свой тип контента, нужно создать отдельный тип записей в Wordpress. Есть таблица с 10 тысячами записей.

Существует ли возможность интегрировать данную таблицу в созданный тип записей?

Comment: Что за таблица? В целом ответ да — есть. Вам нужно данные привести к правильному виду (XML или CSV) и импортировать через плагин, например, https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/

Comment: Есть плагин, в котором не нужно приводить к правильному виду, а сразу брать и импортировать xlsx. Но он не смог импортировать таблицу с 150 000 строк, а не большие таблицы может. Попробуйте в своём случае его - tablepress.

Comment: Таблица в которой информация о врачах. Плюс есть еще таблица с клиниками и множество связных таблиц. Я думал сделать два отдельных типа записей, врачи и клиники и заполнить эти типы записей информацией из существующих таблиц. Возможно я выбрал не правильный инструмент(WordPress) для решения данной задачи?